# Issue converting file object types to String format from an incoming OneDrive REST API call

Tags: rest-api, callout, apexrest, sharepoint

I'm trying to pull a file object-type from O365 via the Graph API and I'm getting back a return-type that is pretty atypical to the normal JSON return format I'd expect to see.  I'm not sure if it's an issue on the Microsoft or Salesforce side. I can't seem to pull any additional information or attributes about the object type itself other than the filename but I do need to change it from an HTTPResponse object to an Apex string before I can do any additional parsing in Salesforce. I can show the snippets of the Apex code I have so far if that would help explain things better.

```
public class apexREST {

    public static HttpResponse restCallout(String callout, String headertype) {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Accept', headertype);
        req.setEndpoint(callout);
        res = new Http().send(req);
        return res;
        }

    public static void getO365file(String spo_site, String spo_fileid) {
        String callout = 'callout:OneDriveCallout/'+spo_site+'/drive/items/'+spo_fileid+'/content';
        String headertype = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';
        system.debug(restCallout(callout, headertype).getBody());
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: So I posted what I have that gets me to the point of seeing the HTTPResponse object. I have a separate class that will take the `restCallout(callout, headertype).getBody()` and parse things further but it can't because it only accepts inputs in the format of a String object, not an HTTPResponse.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/482 , our recommendation would be to get it working outside of Salesforce first.